# WSO2 : Setting up the WSO2 server

Tags: wso2

I'm struggling for 2 days now on setting up wso2 environment (i read the getting started guide like 10 times) for simple test.
All i need is to be able to setup a server and one client.
At the end, I would like to send files from the server to the client, but first, i want to be able to start the server...

currently, when i try to start it, I'm getting the following exception:

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.internal.DataSourceServiceComponent} -  Error in intializing system data sources: Error in initializing system data sources: Error in initializing system data sources at '/home/gidi/Downloads/wso2emm-1.1.0/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml' - null
org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error in initializing system data sources: Error in initializing system data sources at '/home/gidi/Downloads/wso2emm-1.1.0/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml' - null
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceManager.initSystemDataSources(DataSourceManager.java:168)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.internal.DataSourceServiceComponent.initSystemDataSources(DataSourceServiceComponent.java:191)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.internal.DataSourceServiceComponent.setSecretCallbackHandlerService(DataSourceServiceComponent.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bind(ServiceComponentProp.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.securevault.internal.SecretManagerInitializerComponent.activate(SecretManagerInitializerComponent.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error in initializing system data sources at '/home/gidi/Downloads/wso2emm-1.1.0/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml' - null
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceManager.initSystemDataSource(DataSourceManager.java:188)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceManager.initSystemDataSources(DataSourceManager.java:157)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceManager.initSystemDataSource(DataSourceManager.java:183)
    ... 41 more

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I enrolled all my changes and followed the tutorial and successfully registered a device

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had the CARBON_DB in the master-datasources.xml multiple times. After I thinned it down to one copy the ESB started up.